# Weird erratic mesh color(Normals aren't the problem)

Tags: mesh, color

Things I've done:
I've looked for extra vertices.
I've messed with Normals.
I've even tried deleting a section and re-making it. 
I deleted half the mesh, mirrored it, and what's weird, is that the weird color isn't mirrored perfectly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN4dw.png)

[image: The topology isn't weird, no n-gons, no overlapping vertices.]
The topology isn't weird, no n-gons, no overlapping vertices[image]
Normals are fine.

[image: Normals are fine]

[image]

Comment: Add a Subdivision Surface Modifier.

Comment: @cegaton Even though this might be a duplication of 'Why does turning off Auto Smooth removes blotches?' He did not accept the correct answer to his question.

Comment: And furthermore, this question helps out those who don't know about 'Auto Smooth'. I did not previously know about Auto Smooth which means my question will help out beginners find an answer to this problem. It also educates beginners about the existence of n-gons, and Normals. Before posting this question, I looked at the possible questions that might have an answer, but 'Eric Huelin' post did not come up, further proving that my question is more helpful, even though it is in fact a duplicate.

Comment: @JaredWolf "closing" a question as a dup is not a problem. It is actually a good thing. Like you said one of these might not come up, but creating a link between them (closing as a dup) will point one to the other. Twice the chance somebody will get the answer they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normals seem to be the problem.

Go to the Geometry Data section and press on Clear Split Normals.

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem thank you. This way worked and also the subdivision modifier worked as well, but in this instance. 'Clear Custom Split Normals Data' did not alter the design of my model in anyway.  Making this answer more ideal, and less intrusive. Thank you.