# How can I fix Black Patches in my render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor, objects

I am working on a project that is supposed to have an older game kinda feel. Things were going well. However, when I finally decided on my texturing method, which was using nodes in cycles, I ended up with an ugly black patch on the render.

**The normals are all "normal".** **I played with them for quite some time regardless.** This did not work.

**I thought**, based on its appearance, **there may be additional mesh inside the model** that I did not originally intend to be there. I turned on wireframe and looked at all angles. **NO ADDITIONAL MESH!**

Its not on the image texture either.

**I tried removing duplicates as well but still nothing.**

**I've even tried adjusting the original mesh for possible distortion with the unwrap.**

I'm stumped. The black patch overlaps two faces awkwardly. This patch showed up as slightly discolored when I tried texturing it in other methods.

Can anyone help with a solution? **Are there any other possibilities than normals, duplicates, additional mesh** (mesh hiding inside the model causing distortion)**, or mishaps with the texture that could be causing this???**[image]
[image]

Comment: Check for duplicated faces, do Remove Doubles in edit mode. Check for faces that are very close together that can cause Z-fighting, check your normals, and of course check your materials (if you post an image of the nodes used in that area, maybe someone can help). Without info is only a guessing game. The more information you share the easier it is for others to help.

Comment: Try clearing split normals. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109578/weird-erratic-mesh-colornormals-arent-the-problem/109649#109649